# Need to restart Visual Studio 2017 for IIS to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm developing a site with .NET and C# in Visual Studio 2017. When I first load the project, I can press the green arrow IIS Express button and it opens a new browser window and everything is fine. However if I stop it or exit from the browser tab, the next time it doesn't load the page. It opens the browser window, but says it cannot connect, and the IIS Express button doesn't stay grey and goes back to white. This started happening only recently, and I've not made considerable changes to the codebase; I don't know why this is happening now.

All I have to do is exit Visual Studio and open it up again, then I can run IIS Express for one time before it stops working again.

I don't see any errors, I've tried running in Administrator mode, and I've assured that it's not trying to use a port that's already in use. I've also tried updating VS 2017.

Where do I start looking into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may install some third-party extension in your visual stuido that casuing this issue.

I suggest you could try to ​​​​​​run VS with safe mode to check if this is working well or not.

About how to run VS in safe mode, you could refe to below way:

open CMD and go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\version name\Common7\IDE folder, run the command: devenv /safemode

Besides, I suggest you could try to reset all the VS setting to defauly.

Details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1227).